# Currently building an app and I'm getting this message: missing 1 required positional argument: 'skills'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code: [It's saying that the skills call is missing, but I clearly wrote the skills argoument](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlxxL.jpg)

Comment: Please post text as text, not an image of text.

Comment: Sorry, kind of new to stack overflow. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are missing a comma between accounting and bookkeeping so it thinks there are only 3 arguments in your init.

Comment: Wow. Thanks so much man! This is why I love coding, it forces you to pay attention to details. That fixed it lol